# somehow related to us

Tags: word, knowledge, visual

**What is the answer to the puzzle below?**

---

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is...

> SIGN

because

> The pictures represent [Gallaudet ASL hand positions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Sign_Language#/media/File:Asl_alphabet_gallaudet.svg) with the square as the palm and the ovals as digits.

The puzzle title is a reference

> to the fact that this is sign language as used in the US as opposed to the [BANZSL or other systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-handed_manual_alphabets#BANZSL_alphabet)

A tip of the hat for

> the most appropriate use of the visual tag that I can think of.

Comment: That's the answer, great job!

Comment: Nice, I assume I'm not the only person who first interpreted the us in the title as 'us' instead of 'US'.